# Angular 2 - Service worker not found - A bad HTTP response code (404)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, sw-precache

I used `sw-precache` to generate a service worker for a `Firebase` hosted Angular 2 app.

Error:

```
Service Worker registration failed:  TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

Structure

```
src-
  app--
     index.html    
service-worker.js
sw-precache-config.js
```

sw-precache-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  navigateFallback: '../index.html',
  stripPrefix: 'dist',
  root: 'dist/',
  staticFileGlobs: [
    'dist/index.html',
    'dist/**.js',
    'dist/**.css'
  ]
};
```

index.html

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      console.log(navigator.serviceWorker);

      navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js').then(function (registration) {
        console.log('Service Worker registered');
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Service Worker registration failed: ', err);
      });
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service worker registration code seems fine to me.The problem might be in the project structure.Since you have mentioned the root as dist folder, your service-worker.js file must be in the dist folder after you run the `ng build` script. Add `"precache": "sw-precache --verbose --config=sw-precache-config.js"` to your `package.json` scripts object.Then run:
`ng build --prod --aot`,then `npm run precache`.Now your service-worker.js file would be present in the dist folder.Since the angular compiler has compiled your app code into js files and stored it in the dist folder ,now you must serve your app from the dist folder.But the default ng serve doesn't support it.I suggest you to use `http-server`.
`npm install http-server -g`.Then `http-server ./dist -o`.This open up your app on default browser.